# Identify referrer URL after installation through Play Store

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have implemented Deep linking into my App: when the app is installed in the phone, it will open the app, else clicking on the browser it will redirect to the Google Play Store and give user the option to download the app.

My requirement is something like, when the user after clicking on the link gets redirected to Google Play Store and downloads the app, after successful installation of the app, the app should identify the URL from which it got redirected to the play store. I want to know whether it can be done via reading the intent or any other procedure is available to identify the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is called **Deferred Deep Linking** (`Deep Linking` refers to using a link to open your app  directly to a specific piece of content, and `Deferred` means that it works even if the app isn't installed first).

Unfortunately there's no native way to accomplish this on either iOS or Android. The Google Play `INSTALL_REFERRER` could work in theory, but it's unreliable and often gets delivered too late (i.e., seconds to minutes of waiting) to provide a good UX. URL schemes don't work, because they *always* fail with an error if the app isn't installed. [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in iOS 9+ and [App Links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html) on Android 6+ at least don't trigger an *error* if the app isn't installed, but you'd still have to handle redirecting the user from your website to the App Store. You still can't pass context through to the app after install with Universal Links and App Links, so you wouldn't be able to send the user to the correct item.

To make this work, you need a remote server to close the loop. You can [build this yourself](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-build-a-linking-solution-for-every-device), but you really shouldn't for a lot of reasons, not the least of which being you have more important things to do. A free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: they're so awesome I work with them) or Firebase Dynamic Links can handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FCM deep linking check this link [dynamic-links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)

Comment: Can i simple do via InstallReferrerReceiver class and declaring in Manifest?

Comment: action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"